# Confusion with computing surface integral

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Let $F(x,y,z) = \langle x, y, z^2 \rangle$, and $S$ be the unit sphere with radius $1$ about the origin. The question is to find the surface integral $\iint_S F \cdot \text{d} S$. Using the divergence theorem we can compute it to be $8 \pi /3$, but suppose we split the sphere into upper and lower hemispheres and use the formula

$$\iint_S F \cdot \text{d} S = \iint_D \left( -F_1 \partial_x g - F_2 \partial_y g + F_3 \right)\text{d} A$$

where $F_j$ are the components of $F$, $D$ is the unit circle about $0$ in the $xy$-plane, and $g(x,y) = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. Once we split and add the two integrals we get (the first two terms get cancelled, and $F_3=z^2$ gets multiplied by $2$, because it doesn't see the sign of the surface function $g$)

$$\iint_S F \cdot \text{d} S = 2  \iint_D (1-x^2-y^2) \text{d} A = 4\pi \int_0^1 (1-r^2) r \text{d} r = \pi$$

which is a wrong answer. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: My guess would be that the formula is not valid when the function is not constant in the z-coordinate.

Comment: I guess I am making the mistake of orientation, instead of adding the two integrals I should subtract the integral over lower hemisphere from the one over the upper hemisphere, in that case $F_3$'s cancel out and we find $$\iint_S F \cdot dS =2 \iint_D \frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} dA = 4 \pi \int_0^1 \frac{r^3}{\sqrt{1-r^2}} dr$$

Comment: Why are you dividing by $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$?

Comment: @ziggurism it comes from $\partial_x g$ and $\partial_y g$

Comment: @user285292 what is $g$ why are you integrating $g$? you're supposed to be integrating $F$?

Answer (score 0):

If you are integrating a divergenceless vector field over a region bounded by two surfaces, then by Stokes' theorem, the flux into one surface equals the flux out of the other. In that case, when computing the flux through a hemisphere, you could opt to replace it by the equatorial disk, as you have attempted to do.

But your vector field is *not* divergenceless. You have $\nabla \cdot F=2+2z$. The flux integrals of this field are not "independent of surface". You cannot replace the upper hemisphere by the equatorial disk.

Moreover, I'm not sure why you're integrating $\iint F\cdot\nabla g\,dA$. That is neither the flux through the hemisphere, nor through the equatorial plane.

Comment: Isn't this only allowed when the divergence of F is 0? Moreover, you will never obtain the answer 8pi/3 if this would evaluate to 0

Comment: @arriopolis yeah, not sure what I was thinking here. I shall delete.